# Синонимы к слову «умничка»

Tags: синонимы

Какие есть синонимы к слову «умничка»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Например, молодец или молодчина.

Answer (score 2):

*Умница, разумница, умница-разумница, молоток, молодчага,  умняга, голова, большеумница, светлая голова(головушка), умная голова(головушка), золотая голова(головушка), светлый ум, острого ума, талант, голован.*
Можно и что-нибудь новенькое "понапридумать"(от "умница-разумница", например):
*разумничка, умничка-разумничка*.